# Parse a gff file, get scaffold name and creat a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, scaffold

I explain my problem.

I actually have a gff file (Augustus output)
In this gff file I have the localisation of the genes in the differents scaffolds, for exemple:

```
# Predicted genes for sequence number 1 on both strands
# start gene g1
scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    gene    5629    8516    0.13    +   .   g1
scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    transcript  5629    8516    0.13    +   .   g1.t1
scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    start_codon 5629    5631    .   +   0   transcript_id "g1.t1"; gene_id "g1";
scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    intron  5662    7695    0.18    +   .   transcript_id "g1.t1"; gene_id "g1";
scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    intron  8219    8424    0.55    +   .   transcript_id "g1.t1"; gene_id "g1";
scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    CDS 5629    5661    0.41    +   0   transcript_id "g1.t1"; gene_id "g1";
scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    CDS 7696    8218    0.56    +   0   transcript_id "g1.t1"; gene_id "g1";
scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    CDS 8425    8516    0.59    +   2   transcript_id "g1.t1"; gene_id "g1";
scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    stop_codon  8514    8516    .   +   0   transcript_id "g1.t1"; gene_id "g1";
# protein sequence = [MRVKSGNLRENNEARGTSANVALCTVSRGYGGRGARGGGVSGANSGPSGARGGSTRARSRAESVVRLPLSPRTLCAPG
# PVAGPHTGAQAQQHPQQAQSRDHHASQPLTGGAGTGSGLEDGPGSADEPMVHLERPQQAGTWICCVPCYWLRRSKAVHKALLTFAMLLVTSLLVTSPV
# LFLITTLPEAASIRHTYACLFSLSKIPLPPHMKTNGTPF]
# end gene g1
```

Here the g1.t1 is located in the scaffold 0 for exemple.
And I also have a tab file containing several informations such:

```
scaf_name       scaf_length cov_depth       GC
scaffold_0      541519  79.7321515957889    0.398087601727733
scaffold_1      251893  80.0520141488648    0.398288162037055
scaffold_10     169987  79.1650185014148    0.400994512896853
scaffold_100    168110  77.8095354232348    0.417265648727282
scaffold_1000   34744   70.048756619848     0.419531948061824
scaffold_10000  648     73.8009259259259    0.427052956957891
scaffold_100000 118 0   0.401301375405743
scaffold_100001 118 0   0.389793951804145
```

And what I would like to do is to creat a dataframe with those informations, for exemple, if I have 5 genes:

```
g1.t1  in scaffold 256
g2.t1  in scaffold 890
g3.t1  in scaffold 6
g4.t1  in scaffold 6
g5.t1  in scaffold 1234
```

and that in the informations for these scaffolds are:

```
scaf_name       scaf_length cov_depth       GC
scaffold 6      56786         79            0.39
scaffold 256    789765        86            0.42
scaffold 890    3456          85            0.40
scaffold 1234   590           90            0.41
```

I would like to get a dataframe such:

```
gene_name   scaf_name       scaf_length cov_depth       GC
g3.t1       scaffold 6      56786         79            0.39
g4.t1       scaffold 6      56786         79            0.39
g1.t1       scaffold 256    789765        86            0.42
g2.t1       scaffold 890    3456          85            0.40
g5.t1       scaffold 1234   590           90            0.41
```

I guess it is possible to do it with python and pandas is not it?
Thanks for your help :)

Here is the script I made thanks to Ami:

```
import pandas as pd

gff_0042="/Users/etudiant/Desktop/Horizon_project/Augustus/Augustus_out/run_augustus_0042.out"
liste=["scaf_name","source","feature","start","end","score","strand","frame","gene"]
gene_info=pd.read_csv(gff_0042,comment='"',sep='\s+',header=None,names=liste)


scaf_info=pd.read_csv("cov_GC.tab",sep='\t')

scaf_info.scaf_name = scaf_info.scaf_name.str.replace(' ', '_')
new=pd.merge(gene_info, scaf_info, on='scaf_name')

print(new)
```

Here is a part of the output I got:

```
    scaf_name   source  feature start   end score   strand  frame   gene    scaf_length cov_depth   GC  
0   scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    gene    5793    11216   0.13    +   .   g1  541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
1   scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    transcript  5793    11216   0.13    +   .   g1.t1   541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
2   scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    start_codon 5793    5795    .   +   0   transcript_id   541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
3   scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    intron  5829    7371    0.41    +   .   transcript_id   541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
4   scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    intron  7405    7695    0.8 +   .   transcript_id   541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
5   scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    intron  8248    11054   0.37    +   .   transcript_id   541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
6   scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    CDS 5793    5828    0.45    +   0   transcript_id   541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
7   scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    CDS 7372    7404    0.81    +   0   transcript_id   541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
8   scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    CDS 7696    8247    0.84    +   0   transcript_id   541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
9   scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    CDS 11055   11216   0.4 +   0   transcript_id   541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
10  scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    stop_codon  11214   11216   .   +   0   transcript_id   541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
11  scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    gene    38793   39207   0.91    -   .   g2  541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
12  scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    transcript  38793   39207   0.91    -   .   g2.t1   541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
13  scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    stop_codon  38793   38795   .   -   0   transcript_id   541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
14  scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    intron  38904   39066   0.92    -   .   transcript_id   541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
15  scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    CDS 38793   38903   0.95    -   0   transcript_id   541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
16  scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    CDS 39067   39207   0.91    -   0   transcript_id   541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
17  scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    start_codon 39205   39207   .   -   0   transcript_id   541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
18  scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    gene    50409   58153   0.07    +   .   g3  541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
19  scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    transcript  50409   58153   0.07    +   .   g3.t1   541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
20  scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    start_codon 50409   50411   .   +   0   transcript_id   541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
21  scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    intron  50520   50762   0.65    +   .   transcript_id   541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
22  scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    intron  50895   51080   0.91    +   .   transcript_id   541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
23  scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    intron  51180   51284   0.61    +   .   transcript_id   541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
24  scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    intron  51458   55603   0.47    +   .   transcript_id   541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
25  scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    intron  55791   56101   0.98    +   .   transcript_id   541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
26  scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    intron  56279   56384   1   +   .   transcript_id   541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
27  scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    intron  56486   56573   1   +   .   transcript_id   541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
28  scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    intron  56630   56952   0.97    +   .   transcript_id   541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
29  scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    intron  57240   57365   0.57    +   .   transcript_id   541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
30  scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    intron  57525   57736   0.81    +   .   transcript_id   541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
31  scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    intron  57814   58053   0.75    +   .   transcript_id   541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
32  scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    CDS 50409   50519   0.39    +   0   transcript_id   541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
33  scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    CDS 50763   50894   0.74    +   0   transcript_id   541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
34  scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    CDS 51081   51179   0.91    +   0   transcript_id   541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
35  scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    CDS 51285   51457   0.57    +   0   transcript_id   541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
36  scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    CDS 55604   55790   0.98    +   1   transcript_id   541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
37  scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    CDS 56102   56278   0.98    +   0   transcript_id   541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
38  scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    CDS 56385   56485   1   +   0   transcript_id   541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
39  scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    CDS 56574   56629   0.98    +   1   transcript_id   541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
40  scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    CDS 56953   57239   0.64    +   2   transcript_id   541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
41  scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    CDS 57366   57524   0.81    +   0   transcript_id   541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
42  scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    CDS 57737   57813   0.9 +   0   transcript_id   541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
43  scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    CDS 58054   58153   0.5 +   1   transcript_id   541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
44  scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    stop_codon  58151   58153   .   +   0   transcript_id   541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294
```

and I would like if possible to only get :

```
    scaf_name   source  feature start   end score   strand  frame   gene    scaf_length cov_depth   GC  
1   scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    transcript  5793    11216   0.13    +   .   g1.t1   541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
12  scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    transcript  38793   39207   0.91    -   .   g2.t1   541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294 
19  scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    transcript  50409   58153   0.07    +   .   g3.t1   541519  79.7321515957889    0.39808760172773294
```

and so on..

Comment: Where do you see that `g1.t1` is in scaffold 256 *before* the point where you say that this is what you'd like to get?

Comment: It is a hypothetical exemple but you know that a gene is in a scaffold x in the gff file, in my first dataframe for exemple the g1.t1 is in the scaffold 0  (first column)

Comment: It's confusing, I must say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) to read the gff file. Note the following:

- Set `comment='"'`
- Set `sep='\s+'
- Set `header=None`
- Set `names=...` to some list indicating the names, with the first one named `'scaf_name'` and the last one named `'gene'`.

Place it in `gene_info`.

Now use `read_csv` to read the tab limited file, setting `sep='\t'`. Place it in `scaf_info`.

Run

```
scaf_info.scaf_name = scaf_info.scaf_name.str.replace(' ', '_')
```

in order to change stuff like `scaffold 6` to `scaffold_6`.

Now do

```
pd.merge(gene_info, scaf_info, on='scaf_name')
```

Comment: I put the script I used thanks to you and the output I got with some more explanation of the issue.

Comment: @Benjamin Following where you got, is `new[new.feature == 'transcript']` what you're looking for?

Comment: I created another problem I'm facing on here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50300039/parsing-4-dataframe-and-a-fasta-file it is the next step of this issue if you want to take a look?